# Android animation lags after listview scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, nineoldandroids

In my app, I have a top and bottom view.
The bottom view contains a listview, the top an overview of the selected item. When I select an item from the listview, I switch the detailed item in the top view with an animation. 
My problem is, when I scroll the listview, and immediately tap an item, the animation lags a bit. But if I scroll, and wait ~0.5 sec, and then tap, then its smooth.
I tried turning the listview cache off, setting drawing cache on the detailed top view, but nothing helped. Is there some option to make the animations smoother?
I am using NineOldAndroids for animating